# Replication priority

Tags: replication, mongodb

I have two MongoDB instances running on two servers (*instance1* and *instance2*) and they are configured as a replica set. *Instance1* is the primary and *instance2* is the secondary.

When *instance1* was shut down, *instance2* became the primary. However, they both had priority value set to 1. Therefore when *instance1* was up again, *instance2* kept being the primary node.

I changed the priority value of *instance1*=2 and *instance2*=1. If *instance1* is shut down again, *instance2* will become the primary. When *instance1* is up again, will this new priority setting make sure that *instance1* becomes the primary again?

Comment: in theory it should be OK, but why not just execute rs.stepDown() on instance2?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, giving *instance1* a higher priority will make the replicaset re-elect *instance1* as the primary when it rejoins. See the docs on [Adjust Priority for Replica Set Member](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/adjust-replica-set-member-priority/) and [Replica Set Elections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-elections/#member-priority) for more details:

> Member Priority
>
> After a replica set has a stable primary, the election algorithm will make a “best-effort” attempt to have the secondary with the highest priority available call an election. Member priority affects both the timing and the outcome of elections; secondaries with higher priority call elections relatively sooner than secondaries with lower priority, and are also more likely to win. However, a lower priority instance can be elected as primary for brief periods, even if a higher priority secondary is available. **Replica set members continue to call elections until the highest priority member available becomes primary.**